# Max value on multiple statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

```
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+
| ID | Name  | Orderdate | Catalog Price |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+
| 7b | 34-10 | NULL      |          3000 |
| 7b | 34-10 | NULL      |          3000 |
| 7b | 34-10 | NULL      |          2000 |
| 7b | 35-12 | PL-17     |          3000 |
| 8b | 35-11 | PL-18     |          2000 |
| 8b | 34-13 | PL-18     |          2000 |
| 8b | 34-14 | PL-18     |         2000  |
| 8b | 34-15 | PL-18     |         2000  |
| 9b | 35-12 | PL-19     |          2000  
| 9b | 35-11 | PL-19     |          2000 |
| 9b | 34-18 | PL-19     |          2000 |
| 9b | 34-19 | PL-19     |          2000 |
| 9b | 34-20 | PL-19     |          2000 |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

I want a List of the products
where Id starts with 7
where Name starts with 34
where Orderdate = null
and only the records with highest catalog price

Output should be this

```
 ID Name    Orderdate   Catalog Price
7b  34-10   NULL    3000
7b  34-10   NULL    3000
```

i think i am not clear in my explanation so hereby the steps

*step 1* where id starts with 7

```
 ID Name    Orderdate   Catalog Price
    7b  34-10   NULL    3000
    7b  34-10   NULL    3000
    7b  34-10   NULL    2000
    7b  35-12   PL-17   3000
```

*step 2:*where name starts with 34

```
 ID Name    Orderdate   Catalog Price
    7b  34-10   NULL    3000
    7b  34-10   NULL    3000
    7b  34-10   NULL    2000
```

step 3 where orderdate =null

```
ID  Name    Orderdate   Catalog Price
    7b  34-10   NULL    3000
    7b  34-10   NULL    3000
    7b  34-10   NULL    2000
```

step 4:with  the highest catalog price

```
 ID Name    Orderdate   Catalog Price
    7b  34-10   NULL    3000
    7b  34-10   NULL    3000
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgres...?

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Do you actually want duplicated data in your expected output?

Comment: yes that's not a problem as long as the where statements are followed

Answer (score 2):

Please tag your DB. Here's something you can try for Oracle:

```
SELECT id,name,orderdate,catalog_price
FROM TABLE a
WHERE id LIKE '7%' AND name LIKE '34%' AND orderdate IS NULL
  AND catalog_price = (SELECT max(catalog_price) FROM TABLE b 
  WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.name=b.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i have MS SQL

Comment: but i have only one table. so what is table b? sorry i am new to this

Comment: @Kiki it's the same table with different alias. Just replace `TABLE` with your table name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE 
Id LIKE '7%' 
AND Name LIKE '34%' 
AND OrdeDate IS NULL
AND Catalog Price = ( SELECT MAX(Catalog Price) FROM Table )
```

Not quite sure what stands for

```
only the records with highest catalog price
```

if max price within table than my answer is correct if max price grouped by id, name then @django-unchained answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

If you want the max catalog_price per group (id, name, orderdate), you want this

```
select id, name, orderdate, max(catalog_price) as catalog_price
from my_table
where like'7%' and name like'34%' and orderdate is null
group by id, name, orderdate
```

If you don't care for the group, you want this

```
select id, name, orderdate,  catalog_price
from my_table
where id like'7%' and name like'34%' and orderdate is null
and catalog_price = (select max(catalog_price) from my_table)
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fab1a5760d59058573629312ffb7d677)**